FastAPI run_in_threadpool consuming lots of memory and not releasing it after process is killed
I'm running a BackgroundTask in FastAPI that uses Langchain's RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter to split text into chunks. The function is synchronous, and would block the endpoint from returning the response before the BackgroundTask is executed, so I used FastAPI's run_in_threadpool to allow me to await the text splitter. After this addition, the function no longer blocks.
My issue now is that the endpoint consumes a large amount of memory, resulting in worker timeouts. Additionally the memory that the endpoint consumes is not fully recovered after the process is complete. Not sure what to do at this point.
I've created a repository containing a minimal, reproducible example here.
Potentially related posts:
No objects ever released by the GC, potential memory leak?
The memory usage piles up over the time and leads to OOM

Hi, not exactly answer for your problem, but for long jobs you need to add 'task broker' to your server. For example 'taskiq'. So the client sends the task to the fastapi server and immediately recieves a job_ticket (which can be used to retrieve results). FastAPi doesn't process the task itself and sends it to 'taskiq'.

One of the things that you should consider is to limit number of threads used for your blocking task. The fasapi.concurrency.run_in_threadpool function internally calls scarlette.concurrency.run_in_threadpool which calls anyio.to_thread.run_sync. Now the final one by default spawns 40 threads (this is clearly stated in AnyIO docs https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/threads.html). You definitely need to reduce this amount to reduce blocking and free the memory.

Follow the guide from this answer which advises to use Semaphore:
FastAPI `run_in_threadpool` getting stuck

Limit default amount of threads provided by AnyIO. However this may


    from anyio import to_thread
    
    async def foo():
        # Set the maximum number of worker threads to 60
        to_thread.current_default_thread_limiter().total_tokens = 60

Finally I would recommend to create additional layer to your API - a task broker for managing long sync tasks. For example you can use library taskiq.

Hello, Chris, thanks for your comment. If the process like anyio spawns too many threads it is possible that it won't be able clean all of them and their shared memory. Ideally such process should provide a context in which you execute the task. Unfortunately anyio doesn't do this. Thus reducing anyio threads will help with significantly reduce size of this problem or will potentially totally eliminate it. As for the rest of your comment in my answer you can see three solutions to this problem, not the one.

Also I would like to note that the question is not only about badly written langchain library code that consumes a lot of memory, but also about non-cleaned memory after finishing this task. And from my view this part of the question is more important for understanding what is happening: "non cleaned memory afterwards" means that spawned process wasn't cleaned by 'anyio' library and this is highly related to lack of correctly introduced context for executing the task. I've checked RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter function and don't think that the issue is in it.

Sorry for the delayed response. It took me a while to implement a task broker (never used taskiq before). The app is still crashing from multiple calls to /blocking, albeit this time from the following error: RuntimeError: read() called while another coroutine is already waiting for incoming data

Hello, in src/services.py in nonblocking_call replace     text_chunks = await run_async(splitter.split_text, text=text) with text_chunks = splitter.split_text(text). Task is already managed by the broker, you don't need to guard it with Semaphore and etc.
